# How is AOSP build process optimizing my system app's native libraries?

Tags: android, operating-system, android-source

I am building AOSP 10 with a system app, that is provided as pre-built apk.

The system app ships custom native libraries. The original apk which i provide in the AOSP sources contains these libraries compressed (i.e., they can't be used without being [extracted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#extractNativeLibs)). However, after building and installing the OS, the apk contains all native libraries uncompressed, so they can be linked directly from within the apk.

I wonder which AOSP build step precisely is performing this conversion (re-packing the apk, storing all `.so` files uncompressed). I have checked `signapk` and `zipalign`, however both only seem to provide proper alignment for uncompressed files, not reverting the compression itself.

(My background is that I would like to replace the apk as a custom post-build step)

Here's the app's `Android.mk`

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := MyAppName
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MyAppName.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_APPS)
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: Would be great if you could share the Android.bp or the Android.mk file you are using to add the app to the build!

Answer (score 2):

in `build/make/core/definitions.mk` I found this defition:

```
# Uncompress shared JNI libraries embedded in an apk.
#
define uncompress-prebuilt-embedded-jni-libs
  if (zipinfo $@ 'lib/*.so' 2>/dev/null | grep -v ' stor ' >/dev/null) ; then \
    $(ZIP2ZIP) -i $@ -o $@.tmp -0 'lib/**/*.so' \
      $(if $(PRIVATE_EMBEDDED_JNI_LIBS), \
        -x 'lib/**/*.so' \
        $(addprefix -X ,$(PRIVATE_EMBEDDED_JNI_LIBS))) && \
    mv -f $@.tmp $@ ; \
  fi
endef
```

apparently, `zip2zip ... -0 'lib/**/*.so'` does the conversion I was looking for, being used in `build/make/core/app_prebuilt_internal.mk`.

Comment: My recommendation would be to also use this flag in addition in the app Android.mk
LOCAL_PREBUILT_JNI_LIBS